# Save visitor details (added through addCustomDetail) in LiveChatVisitor

Tags: liveagent

I have Live Chat configured in my salesforce application. I'm tracking the source URL before the user clicks the live chat button through

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail('source_url', window.location.href, false);
```

The source URL is visible in Live Chat under Visitor Details when a live agent is talking to a customer. How can I save this URL in a custom field in the Live Chat Transcript object? Or any other place in SF for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer from a salesforce code sample:

```
liveagent.addCustomDetail('Company', 'Acme').saveToTranscript('Company__c')
```

This line will save the custom detail in a custom field in the LiveChatTranscript record.

Comment: hi, I did this, but I am only seeing the custom detail value. The value doesn't show up in the custom field. What could I be missing here?